# Function to create a list of lists

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, collections

I need to create a function named stats to return a list of lists where the first item in each inner list is the teacher's name and the second item in the number of courses that teacher has. 
It should return: [["Tom Smith", 6], ["Emma Li", 3]]

Argument is a dictionary that looks like:

```
teacher_dict = {'Tom Smith': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'Emma Li': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def stats(teacher_dict):
    big_list = []
    for teacher, courses in teacher_dict.items():
        number_of_courses = []
            for key in teacher_dict:
            teacher = ''
            num = 0
            for item in teacher_dict[key]:
                num += 1
            number_of_courses.append((key,num))
    return big_list.append([teacher, number_of_courses])
```

Another attempt:

```
def stats(teacher_dict):
    big_list = []
    for teacher in teacher_dict.items():
        number_of_courses = len(teacher_dict[teacher])
    return big_list.append([teacher, number_of_courses])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Both scripts have errors, and I am still very junior in Python, but really want to figure this out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please detail the problem(s) with your attempts at solving this problem.

Comment: Yes, also stick to one implementation and I suggest trying to write some code that tests your method and prints the output so we can copy and paste your code. The less drudge work we have to do, the more helpful the community becomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension

```
[[k, len(v)] for k, v in teacher_dict.items()]
```

Comment: I always appreciate a one-line, clean, simple solution. IMO, this is the easiest to understand for beginners.

Comment: This looks so simple! Can't believe it, thank you Patrick. Could you explain why did you use the .items() method?

Comment: @MaiiaS. `items` provides a view of the dictionary, which you can basically think of as a list of tuples like `[('Tom Smith', ['a', 'b', 'c']), ...]` where the first element of the tuple is they key in the dictionary and the second element is that keys value.  When you iterate over a dictionary directly `for x in d` you're actually only iterating over the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
teacher_dict = {'Tom Smith': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'Emma Li': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
stats = lambda teacher_dict: [[teacher, len(courses)] for teacher, courses in teacher_dict.items()]
stats(teacher_dict)
```

Outputs:
    [['Emma Li', 3], ['Tom Smith', 6]]

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is almost good to go, problem is that the `return` statement ends the function prematurely. Also the `append` call must be inside the loop:

```
def stats(teacher_dict):
    big_list = []
    for teacher in teacher_dict.items():
        number_of_courses = len(teacher_dict[teacher])
        big_list.append([teacher, number_of_courses])
    return big_list
```